# Interleaving function with different length strings

Tags: c, pointers

I'm trying to build a function that interleaves two strings together regardless of size (Although it can be assumed to be under 100 characters) and outputs a pointer to a new string.

```
char* interleaved(const char* s1, const char* s2){
    char *word = malloc (sizeof (char) * 100);
    const char *p = s1;
    const char *p2 = s2;
    int i = 0;
    while(*p != '\0' || *p2 != '\0'){
        if(i%2 == 0){
            word[i] = *p;
            p++;
        }
        if(i%2 == 1){
            word[i] = *p2;
            p2++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    if(*p == '\0'){
        while(*p2 != '\0'){
            word[i] = *p2;
            p2++;
            i++;
        }
    }
    if(*p2 == '\0'){
        while(*p != '\0'){
            word[i] = *p;
            p++;
            i++;
        }
    }
    word[i] = '\0';
    return word;
}
```

Currently it will work if both strings are the same length, eg 'dog' and 'cat' will produce 'dcoagt', but if the strings are uneven eg 'dogbird' and 'cat' I get 'dcoagtb', and if the second string is longer I just get 'dcoagt'. Something has to be wrong in my two if statements after the original while loop but I'm not sure what it is, can someone have a look and help me?

Cheers

Answer (score 3):

The very first loop should use `&&` instead of `||`.

```
while(*p != '\0' && *p2 != '\0')
```

Using `&&` causes it to stop as soon as either string is exhausted. Using `||` makes it continue until *both* strings are exhausted. That's bad because the shorter string's pointer will run right off the end into no man's land.

Comment: Ahhh awesome that fixed it all, in my head the logic was "Keep looping until either p or p2 point to null" but I see it needed to be "Keep looping while p1 and p2 do not equal null"

Answer (score 0):

You've got the primary problem resolved by [John Kugelman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/68587/john-kugelman) in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25756600/15168), but the code is rather verbose.  You could write:

```
char *interleaved(const char *s1, const char *s2)
{
    char *word = malloc(strlen(s1) + strlen(s2) + 1);
    if (word == 0)
        return 0;
    int i = 0;
    const char *p1 = s1;
    const char *p2 = s2;
    while (*p1 != '\0' && *p2 != '\0')
    {
        word[i++] = *p1++;
        word[i++] = *p2++;
    }
    while (*p1 != '\0')
        word[i++] = *p1++;
    while (*p2 != '\0')
        word[i++] = *p2++;
    word[i] = '\0';
    return word;
}
```

Note that this checks that the memory allocation succeeded.  The code allocates the requisite amount of space; it neither wastes space when short strings are passed nor fails when long strings are passed.

The loops are more compact, making full use of the `++` operators.  The `if` tests are redundant.  At the end of the main loop, the body of at most one of the two following loops will ever be executed (the one for the longer string, or neither if the input strings are the same length).

I kept `p1` (well, renamed `p` to `p1`) and `p2`, but the code could equally as well use `s1` and `s2` instead.  I also retained the subscript `i` and used the `word[i++]` notation; it would have been feasible to use `char *dst = word;` and then `*dst++` in place of `word[i++]` throughout (`*dst` in place of `word[i]`, of course).  This might even be microscopically more efficient — but that's not a reason to use the notation; symmetry, on the other hand, is a reason to use the notation.

Those changes lead to:

```
char *interleaved(const char *s1, const char *s2)
{
    char *word = malloc(strlen(s1) + strlen(s2) + 1);
    if (word == 0)
        return 0;
    char *dst = word;
    while (*s1 != '\0' && *s2 != '\0')
    {
        *dst++ = *s1++;
        *dst++ = *s2++;
    }
    while (*s1 != '\0')
        *dst++ = *s1++;
    while (*s2 != '\0')
        *dst++ = *s2++;
    *dst = '\0';
    return word;
}
```

Comment: Ahh I really like that. I will say that pointers are not my strong suit, but I do understand what you did there. Thank you!